# Invalid rownames length error while constructing a SingleCellExperiment Object

Tags: r, seurat, rna-seq

I am trying to perform single cell data analysis using Bayesspace package in R. For that, I need to construct a SingleCellExperiment object. I have tried the following code,

```
colData \<- read.csv("kidneydata/kidney085_XY01_20-0038/spa.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
counts \<- read.csv("kidneydata/kidney085_XY01_20-0038/count.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

names(colData) \<- c("row","col")

sce \<- SingleCellExperiment(list(counts=counts),
                            colData=colData
)
```

I get the following error, when I try to execute the code above,

```
Error in `rownames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = .get_colnames_from_first_assay(assays)) : 
  invalid rownames length
```

Can someone help me to solve this error?

Here is the counts data,

[image]

It has 317 observations of 14975 variables.

And here is the glimpse of coordinates data,

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Transposing the counts matrix has solved the issue as the SingleCellExperiment class expects cells as columns and genes as rows in the counts data.